# Make R wait for console input?

Tags: r, user-interaction

Is there a way to make R wait for console input before continuing?
Let's say I source two scripts like this in a main script called run.R:

```
# some more R Code here

source("script1.R")
source("script2.R")

# some more R Code there
```

Script1 contains some `readLine` statement that asks the user for a username. 
Unfortunately if I just run the entire run.R file R doesn't wait for the username to be entered. It starts script2.R before the username is entered which leads to an error because the 2nd script needs the username.

I have an ugly workaround for this using R Studio's `.rs.askForPassword` which actually waits for the the input, but covers the password. Which is cool for passwords, but not so much for usernames. Plus it's an RStudio feature, not R.

Comment: You can look at jverzani [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311747/add-a-popup-text-box-within-an-r-script-using-tcltk), it's doable with `tcltk`.

Comment: Hm, probably would not work on Rstudio server then? Or is tcltk als available from standard browser config?

Answer (score 4):

`readline` can only be used in interactive sessions. In non-interactive use of `readline` the result is an empty string. On the help page of `?interactive` you find the following about interactive sessions:

> GUI consoles will arrange to start R in an interactive session. When R
>   is run in a terminal (via Rterm.exe on Windows), it assumes that it is
>   interactive if ‘stdin’ is connected to a (pseudo-)terminal and not if
>   ‘stdin’ is redirected to a file or pipe. Command-line options
>   --interactive (Unix) and --ess (Windows, Rterm.exe) override the default assumption.

Comment: Ok, thx. I see now `readline` is not the way to go. Your answers does help to understand what I was guessing. But is there a way to circumvent this, i.e. use another function? I typically run R from RStudio.

Answer (score 4):

Try `scan` function.

This is `test.R` file:

```
y <- 2
cat('y=',y)
cat("\nEnter username")
x <- scan(what=character(),nmax=1,quiet=TRUE)
"ala ma kota"
y <- 2*2
cat('y=',y)
cat('\nx=',x)
```

and then I run this:

```
> source("test.R")
y= 2
Enter username
1: login
y= 4
x= login
```

--edit--
To read only one character quietly run this:

```
> x <- scan(what=character(),nmax=1,quiet=TRUE)
1: username
> x
[1] "username"
```

`what` sets the type, `nmax` sets the maximal numbers of elements to read and `quiet` determine if print a line, saying how many items have been read.

Comment: Hmm, `scan` throws an error that it only accepts 'real' but usernames are characters often...

Comment: Is there an argument for to prompt something? Like "Enter username". Or would you just cat() it?

Comment: :( Actually this does not work either... script is executed before name is entered...

Comment: Works for me, check my post now. Maybe you've done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why not putting

```
source("script2.R")
```

into the file script1.R?